# jQuery malfunctions another script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to build a radio-enabled search box, and with a little search, I found what I was looking for. I was trying to make the buttons look like toggles so I ran into [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/Zgh24/1/)! I liked it. It's what I was looking for. But, once I added jQuery, the whole search thing didn't work anymore. And to be honest, I have no idea why. Here's the HTML with jQuery :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function dosearch() {
  var sf=document.searchform;
  for (i=sf.sengines.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
    if (sf.sengines[i].checked) {
      var submitto = sf.sengines[i].value + escape(sf.searchterms.value);
    }
  }
  window.location.href = submitto;
  return false;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#sites input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
$('#sites label').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
})
</script>
<style>
.input_hidden {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
.selected {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
#sites label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#sites label:hover {
    background-color: #efefef;
}
#sites label img {
    padding: 3px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sites">
<form name="searchform" onSubmit="return dosearch();">
<input id='first' name="sengines" type="radio" checked='checked' value="http://myurl.com/search?q="/><label for="first"><img src="http://sstatic.net/serverfault/img/favicon.ico" alt="Server Fault" /></label>
<input id='req' name="sengines" type="radio" value="http://www.myotherurl.com/search?q="/><label for="req"><img src="http://sstatic.net/superuser/img/favicon.ico" alt="Super User" /></label>
<input type="text" name="searchterms"/>
</form></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Remove jQuery and the function will work. 
jQuery is critical and I can't just delete it from code. Other parts of the original webpage are heavily using it.

Comment: The jsFiddle you linked to already includes jQuery, but an old version - are you sure you're not doing it twice in your code?

Comment: `for(var i;...` - DO initialise `i` with `var`!

Comment: Have you looked at the javascript console. If it doesn't work maybe there was an error with your copy and pasting.

Comment: The JS console will not prompt an error in this case. There is no error! The only mistake is that he forgot to actually instantiate the jQuery part to be executed when the DOM is fully loaded (or, as you said, an error with copy+pasting ;)).

Comment: @Tomas Lycken, I tried the latest version and older versions. none of them worked. So I decided to stick with 1.7.2, which is in use on the main webpage.

@ Tomas Zato. Tried, didn't work. Thank you anyway ^^ر

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copy+pasted the code from the fiddle as is. But since the seperated HTML, JS and CSS  parts are being put together, you missed an important part: to actually instantiate the jQuery part to be executed when the DOM is fully loaded.

In the fiddle, the [final source code](http://fiddle.jshell.net/yijiang/Zgh24/1/show/) gives you:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#sites input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
$('#sites label').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
});//]]>    
</script>
```

**Update**: Furthermore, you did not closed the script tag correctly when including jQuery. This broke the functionality of the code within the script tag right after the jQuery include.

This `<script src="jquery.js"/>` should read `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`

Here is a fully working version now:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .input_hidden {position: absolute; left: -9999px;}
    .selected {background-color: #ccc;}
    #sites label {display: inline-block; cursor: pointer;}
    #sites label:hover {background-color: #efefef;}
    #sites label img {padding: 3px;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="sites">
    <form name="searchform" id="s">
      <input id='first' name="sengines" type="radio" checked='checked' value="http://myurl.com/search?q=">
      <label for="first" class="selected"><img src="//sstatic.net/serverfault/img/favicon.ico" alt="Server Fault"></label>
      <input id='req' name="sengines" type="radio" value="http://www.myotherurl.com/search?q=">
      <label for="req"><img src="//sstatic.net/superuser/img/favicon.ico" alt="Super User"></label>
      <input type="text" name="searchterms" id="searchterms">
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $().ready(function() {
    $('#sites input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
    $('#sites label').click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    });
    $('#s').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location.href = $(this).find(':checked').val() + $('#searchterms').val();
      return !0;
    });
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This fixed adding classes problem. But still "window.location.href" thing doesn't work. Thank you anyway ^^ر

Comment: Got it. You forgot to close the jQuery script tag and thus broke the functionality of the JS part. See my updated answer for a fully working code version.

Comment: You're the best eyecatchUp (: Thank you very much ^^ر